# Getting employee name and the next employee whose salary is more than current employee

Tags: sql

I am working on preparing an sql query where I want to get the employee name as first result and the next employee whose salary is more than current employee.

Here is my table with data:

```
Employee table:

A with Salary 500
B with Salary 100
C with Salary 1000
```

Now my output should be:

```
A C
B A
B C
```

I am not able to figure out what kind of query gives me this result.

Comment: what if there are ties?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Comment: I am using Oracle, want to try this in mysql also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `select a.employee_name, b.employee_name from table a,table b where a.employee_name !=b.employee_name and a.salary<b.salary;` this checks if the employee name is not equal in the other set and salary is greater than the a's salary then print those and If there are more employees with greater than sal of current you need to use `IN` clause